# Dont' use default value for double

Tags: c#, asp.net, default-value

Using C# in ASP.NET, I want to take the result of two text fields, add them when a button is pressed, and display the result. However, if one or both of the fields are empty, I don't want any result shown.

Right now I keep getting 0 as the result if both fields are empty. I'm pretty sure this is because the two input numbers (doubles) are being assigned a default 0. How can I check for empty fields?

This is my method in my controller.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult French(FrenchModel model, string returnUrl)
    {

        switch (model.operation)
        {
            case 1:
                model.result = model.numberOne + model.numberTwo;
                break;
            case 2:
                model.result = model.numberOne - model.numberTwo;
                break;
            case 3:
                model.result = model.numberOne * model.numberTwo;
                break;
            case 4:
                model.result = model.numberOne / model.numberTwo;
                break;
        }


        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 13):

Doubles are value types and thus cannot be assigned to null or "empty".  If you want this capability, try using a nullable double.  Either `Nullable<double>` or `double?` should work.

Be aware, using a nullable value type you will need to check it for null before you use it or risk a `NullReferenceException` whereas `double` defaults to `0` if unassigned.

Comment: Thanks. I switched my "double" to "double?", and it works when not entering anything. However, I'm not checking for errors and it's not crashing.

Comment: I didn't run into NullReferenceException for the testing I was doing.

I was testing a method to see if it was properly assigning a new value to a double. To test this, I checked against default(double) which only worked for some of this class's methods (I didn't make the class or have access to its source) but when I changed my problem values from double to double?, and subsequently my comparison to default(double?), all was right in the kingdom once more.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Double?` ie nullable Double, its default value is null and you'll assign a value only if textbox is not empty and you can parse it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to determine if one or both of the fields are empty. Refactor as you need with your particular variables.

```
string one = txt1.Text;  
string two = txt2.Text;

string result = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(one) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(two))
                 ?string.Empty
                 :double.Parse(one) + double.Parse(two);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if statements:

```
    if (operand1 != 0) { // do something.. }
    else { // do something.. }
```

You can also do this for the second operand